# What is the proper way to revert back to a previous merge after pushing to remote master on group project?

Tags: git, github

I made some changes on a branch, committed them, merged with master and pushed to master. But we discovered on one of our servers it causes a huge problem. Now I want to revert the remote origin master back to before my merge. I've read that on group projects, you need to use different commands to properly revert. What are they?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `git revert commmitId`

Comment: But what about pushing that revert to remote origin master?

Comment: you need to do that explicitely by `git push`. revert command will do a revert commit for you.  You nned to push that to remote

Comment: Is commitId the one I want to revert *to*? Or the one I want to undo?

Comment: commitID of commit you want to undo

Comment: What if that commit (a merge) includes a bunch of commits? How do I undo them all?

Comment: you need to do `git revert commitid -m 1`

Comment: What if no one else has made any changes since this commit? Can I do a reset and erase it as part of the history?

Comment: @DonRhummy Keep in mind that you just rewrote the history of this published branch.  This could cause problems for anyone else who is using it.  `git revert` is usually the way to go for published branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How could it cause trouble? No one has made any commits or pulls or pushes since before I made the one I'm resetting to. Can it still cause issues?

Comment: @DonRhummy In this case there is no problem.  But I added the comment because in general there is a risk with force pushing a public branch.  Your situation is an exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @DonRhummy It would not cause problem in your case as no activity is performed while you commited and reverted. But in short the practice you followed can lead to problems